# Select * from most recent records

Tags: mysql, sql

How to go about selecting all data from the most recent three records in table. This is specifically for a blog that on the home page will show the three most recently dated articles.

```
ID |title      |date      |...
---------------------------
1  |exampTitle1|2018-04-25|
2  |exampTitle2|2019-02-10|
3  |exampTitle3|2007-12-21|
4  |exampTitle4|2019-08-10|
```

The example table shows a subsection of the table, I need to select all data from each record but only from the most recent THREE records, I am aware of MAX() but as far as I am aware that can only get the most recent, not

Comment: Did you try ORDER BY with LIMIT?

Answer (score 3):

In SQL, you can order the rows with `ORDER BY`. Then, you can `LIMIT` what you are selecting with the `LIMIT 3` spesific to SQL of some DBMS products such as `MySQL` :

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, by sorting by ID in descending order and using LIMIT:

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Won't work as 'id' isn't necessarily in order of the publication.

Comment: So date then? Is there any way to actually know which is the latest three beyond just being the last three rows in the table?

Comment: OK, at this point you might need to consider whether the schema used for the table suits your needs because this should have been a trivial problem yet it apparently isn't.